# How display xml content with nodes from a jsp

Tags: xml, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp which calls a servlet which inturn calls a webservice. The response xml of webservice is returned to the jsp. Now in the front end the xml content is displayed with out the nodes..How to display the xml as xml(with nodes)? can anyone pls help?

Comment: Can your describe `xml as xml(with nodes)` here ?

Comment: dont parse it, simply display all data.

Comment: if you are getting the wsdl from the url just read the wsdl from the url and display it using out.println()

Comment: Im making an ajax call from the browser here. The xml is getting printed as plain text..For eg: if the returned responsexml in <OperationDay>Sat</OperationDay>. Then it is displayed as just Sat in browser . I want the nodes also to appear in the browser.

Comment: out.println wont work for ajax call na.

Comment: wanted to view the raw xml in the browser

Comment: the servlet is returning you the url of the wsdl right?

Comment: servlet is returning the response xml of the restful webservice call.

Comment: if you already got the xml just display it as it is. May be u are parsing it before displaying

Comment: im not parsing it.. :(

Comment: are you sure the servlet send you the file in xml format. Is it sending you the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Verrry simple solution...I replaced all "<" with & lt; and all ">" with & gt; before returning the xml :).
I could see the xml as it is in the browser .

Comment: that means you dint use this `<%@ page contentType="text/xml" %>` in your jsp